# Mvvm Cross 6.0 Tabbed Application

Tags: framework

I want to develop a Tabbed Application in Xamarin.Android, using MvvmCross 6.0.
My application needs to have 4 tabs, each tab having 2-3-4 levels.
Can you recommend me any tutorial or Git repository that might be helpful for my problem. 
I have been investigating this for almost 4 hours and all the things that I find on Internet are with Xamarin.Forms and I didn`t succeed in making the transition to Xamarin.Android.

Comment: Welcome! We don't recommend tutorials here, but I hope that you will find a GitHub repository to help you